# Symfony 2 Assetic CSS not redering with working paths

Tags: css, symfony, rendering, assetic

I've read all the issues on css paths that does not render correctly. Dumping Assetic, installing with --symlink those awnsers don't apply to me. Have tried most of the topics i've found here.

The problem I'm facing is that there the css links are working correctly. The image urls are pointing to the right direction.

But still. No styling is applied, nothing, JS is running correctly.

I've set 'use controller' to false in my configs. 
I'm not using the uglifier.

These problems occurred on the production environment. On my local machine it's working fine.

Any ideas or suggestions?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Validate your CSS, than you will find out that on of the files that are merged has a ")" on the end of the file. 
If they are called separately there is no invalid css 'under' it. 
When files are merged it has.. 
That why!